# DataGrid button, command binding relative source up the tree not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a data grid with few text columns and a Delete button:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Customers, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCustomer}"> 
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FirstName}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                        <Label Content="{DynamicResource FirstName}" />
                    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LastName}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                        <Label Content="{DynamicResource LastName}" />
                    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Address}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                        <Label Content="{DynamicResource Address}" />
                    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                </DataGridTextColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Content="{DynamicResource Delete}" Command="{Binding DeleteCustomerCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedCustomer, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Having read this question and answer:

[How to use RelativeSource Binding to create DataGrid binding to Model and ViewModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863408/how-to-use-relativesource-binding-to-create-datagrid-binding-to-model-and-viewmo)

I addded the

```
RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}
```

part. However, nothing works still. When I debug with [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/), I can see DataContexts are properly set. The datacontext of the `DataGrid` is the ViewModel, and it uses the `Customers` collection property, and the data context of the grid rows are the individual `Customer` objects, which is expected. 
I have checked that commands are referred to with their real names and that they're public. Command is initialized in the ViewModel's constructor:

```
 DeleteCustomerCommand = new RelayCommand<Customer>(DeleteCustomer);
```

and the Commands are public properties with private setters:

```
public RelayCommand<Customer> DeleteCustomerCommand { get; private set; }
```

I only get the following error:

> DeleteCustomerCommand' property not found on 'object' ''DataGrid'
>   (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=DeleteCustomerCommand;
>   DataItem='DataGrid' (Name=''); target element is 'Button' (Name='');
>   target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

Comment: Have you checked for any binding errors in the output window when clicking the button?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try add "DataContext" to your command binding:

```
Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteCustomerCommand, RelativeSource=...
```

because there is no `DeleteCustomerCommand` property on your `DataGrid` but in the view model connected with the `DataGrid`.

**Additional info**

Sometimes it helps me to create a binding for a `DataContext` with the Visual Studio assistant instead of coding it completely by hand.
Just look for the property you want to create a binding for in the property grid of the control.

In this case its the `Command` property. Left click on the text box for the command property text, then choose "Create data binding..." from the context menu.

Comment: thanks for the additional info. It will definitely come in handy!